# Detect english words in text

Tags: java, python, mysql, dictionary, data-cleaning

I have a dataset which is crawled but also contains entries that have a lot of junk in them.

```
Name: sdfsdfsdfsd
Location: asdfdgdfjkgdsfjs
Education: Science & Literature
```

Currently its being stored in MySQL and Solr.
Is there any library that can look for English words in these fields so that i may eliminate the garbage values? I believe it would need a dictionary and the default unix dictionary in **/usr/share/dict/** seems enough for this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    words = set(word.lower() for word in f.read().split()
                # Really short words aren't much of an indication
                if len(word) > 3)

def is_english(text):
    return bool(words.intersection(text.lower().split()))
    # or
    return any(word in words for word in text.lower().split())

print(is_english('usfdbg dsuyfbg cat'))
print(is_english('Science & Literature'))
```

Comment: this would imply a O(n^2) complexity since I'd have to scan the entire list for every row in my dataset.

Comment: @YashveerRana no, the point of a set is constant time lookups for each item. `is_english` is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of words in `text` and there's no way you can do better than that.